# Metadata as parameter in route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have my playload serialized:

```
count:949
next:null
previous:null
results: Array(949)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 399]
[400 … 499]
[500 … 599]
[600 … 699]
[700 … 799]
[800 … 899]
[900 … 948]
length: 949
```

The url parameters is *limit* and *offset*. As default it's display 20 records each, like http://localhost/data?limit=20. My router is this.store.query('model', {limit:949}); to return all data that i need, but if new records are added i have to change the limit value and this is not good.

Is there a way to pass the "***meta: count***" as query parameter in 
 this.store.query('model', ***{limit: meta:count}***); to return all data? Or

Comment: why aren't you just using `findAll()` ?

Comment: Because the return is default data (20 records).

Comment: I think maybe you can do a Ternary operator. When you wanna return all the data, you do use findAll(), otherwise you return the limit param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, since I don't have access to the API you are consuming, but I would try something like this:

```js
import { get } from '@ember/object';
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({

  model() {

    return get(this, 'store').query('modelName', {}).then(results => {

      const { count } = get(results, 'meta');

      return get(this, 'store').query('modelName', { limit: count });

    });

  },

});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works!!! I was trying something very similar and now I realized that I was so close.